# deleting a range of rows in enothught canopy

Tags: python, pandas, canopy

Here is my Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
dfa = df = pd.read_csv("twitDB3__org.csv")
dfa.drop([7-100], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

**Output**

```
ValueError: labels [-93] not contained in axis
```

I am new to canopy and want to delete a range of rows and it seems to require each row individual. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

a) I think you want `dfa.drop(range(7,101),...` (What you did was just subtract 100 from 7 and pass the result (-93) as the label to drop.)

b) Note that this will also change `df`, because as you've written it, `df` and `dfa` are just two names for the same mutable object. If you want to end up with two different dataframes, then either make an explicit copy, or don't use `inplace`, and save the result: `df2 = df.drop(...`

c) This is a pandas question, not a canopy question. Canopy provides 500+ Python packages, and while it's true that pandas is one of the more popular of these, there is a whole pandas community out there.